# mail() function ini_set() smtp server localhost not work

Tags: php, html, smtp

```
 <?php

  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {


  $admin_email = "example@gmail.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
   $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];


   ini_set("SMTP","localhost");
   ini_set("smtp_port","25");
   ini_set("sendmail_from",$email);

   mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);
    echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
   }


   else  {
  ?>

  <form method="post">
   Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
   Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
   Message:<br />
  <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

  <?php
  }
 ?>
```

**error**

> mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()**

Comment: Do you have a mail server running on your machine?

Comment: use phpmailer for smtp

Comment: i have no any mail server in my machine

Comment: You just gave yourself the explanation why it does not work. Thx @jiri-hrazdil!